# Number Stored as Text gives an error

Tags: c#, excel

when I read a field `dt.Rows[0][j]`, I always get `null` in spite of data being in the excel sheet .

How can I suppress error caused due to number stored as text?

This is the code that I am using.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
{
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 2; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j += 3)
        {
            try
            {

                var s3 = sheetName.Remove(sheetName.Length - 1);
                s3 = s3.Replace("'", string.Empty);
                s3 = s3.Replace("$", string.Empty);
                if (s3[0] == '0') { s3 = s3.Remove(0, 1); }

                if ((!dt.Rows[0][j].ToString().Contains("total")))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Budget]([CA TTC],[VAL MRG TTC],[CA HT],[VAL MRG HT],[Rayon],[Date],[Code Site],[Rayon Correspondance]) VALUES(@ca,@val,@catHT ,@valHT ,@rayon, @date ,@sheetName,null )", con);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dt.Rows[i][0]);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ca", dt.Rows[i][j]);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", dt.Rows[i][j + 1]);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rayon", dt.Rows[0][j].GetType());
                    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][j].GetType().ToString());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sheetName", s3);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@catHT", DBNull.Value).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@valHT", DBNull.Value).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

[image]

[image]

I read `dt` with the following code

```
var dt = new DataTable();
string query = string.Format("SELECT  * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: And if you want to use this woodoo by @jon-skeet to format your question next time, paste your code to VS. It will do the all magic formatting.

Comment: How are you reading the Excel data into `dt`?

Comment: @E.Z.Hart I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly believe you are confusing between the cell which has data and the cell which the code is pointing at. Please double check what cell `dt.Rows[0][j]` is referring to. See what is the value of `j` at the time of error. That will help you narrow down to the cell in question.

The code will not fail on the cell if it contains numbers stored as text. Here is a simple way to test it.

Create an Excel file and save it as say `C:\MyFile.xlsx`. In Cell `A2`, type `'1`. The `'` will ensure that the number is stored as text.

[image]

Now, use this code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection Conn;

        Conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(
        "provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\\MyFile.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;");

        var dt = new DataTable();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT  * FROM [{0}]", "Sheet1$");
        Conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Conn);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    }
```

You will get `1` in the message box.

[image]